# Pentaho 6.1 BI CE - Why is there no Authentication button in the Administration section?

Tags: pentaho

I read this article on how to configure LDAP Authentication on Pentaho 6.1:

https://support.pentaho.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360007845791/Configuring_Pentaho_with_LDAP_or_Active_Directory.pdf

When I clicked on the Administration section, I noticed that the Authentication panel is not present.
[Administration Panel - Pentaho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJVmm.jpg)

Can you help me?

Comment: I think you first need to configure it manually: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0P0/150/010/030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document is only for Enterprise Edition. You may have the community edition. Has the same capability, but no UI to configure it, you must edit the relevant files by hand.

All files are in pentaho-solutions/system folder.

Two are relevant if your solution is standard: in security.properties change provider to ldap; the other file is a properties file just for ldap configuration, replace all ldap queries for your specific ones. No other modifications are necessary.